# Timer not disposed when form is

Tags: c#, winforms, timer, dispose

I am trying to understand why a `Windows.Forms.Timer` is not disposed when the `form` that created it is. I have this simple form:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {

    private System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer;

    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = 1000;
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(OnTimer);
        timer.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void OnTimer(Object source, EventArgs e) {
        Debug.WriteLine("OnTimer entered");
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e) {
        this.Dispose();
    }
}
```

When I close it, `this.Dispose` is called but the timer firing event continues to be called. I thought that the `Dispose` was freeing all objects owned by the disposed object. Is that untrue? Does `Timer` have a specific behavior?

For now, I found that the way to dispose of the timer is to do `timer.Tick -= OnTimer;` - I call it then in the `Form1_FormClosed` event. Is it the good solution or should I do otherwise?

## EDIT

Or is it simply better to do:

```
private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e) {
    timer.Dispose();
    this.Dispose();
}
```

?

Comment: The disposing should be done in the `IDisposable` method `Dispose`, not in `FormClosing`

Comment: in `FormClosing` event you should stop timer `timer.Enabled = false;` and then `timer.Dispose(); timer = null;`

Comment: @OskarKjellin: How is it better to override `Dispose` rather to do it in `FormClosed`?

Comment: @Marco: What's the use of `timer.Enabled = false;` and `timer = null;` when you do `timer.Dispose();`? Isn't `Dispose()` taking care of everything?

Comment: @Otiel: be careful that disposing an object is not the same as assigning null. If you use `timer.Dispose()` and later you try to access timer you got an exception; so, if you know some object could have been deleted, you can check `if (timer != null) ...` but this is false if you just disposed it, so you got an exception executing code. So it's a good idea to dispose and set to null to be sure that in your code you don't use that object again after it has been disposed...

Comment: @Otiel Because that is exactly what `Dispose` is made for. To dispose managed resources.

Comment: Drop a timer from the toolbox onto the form with the designer.  Now it is all automatic.

Comment: @HansPassant could you explain this in detail? It really works automaticlly now, when you drop the timer from the toolbox. But the only difference I found in code is that it uses the other constructor overload `this.timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer(this.components)`

Comment: @HansPassant and is there a way to use this approach manually in code, when there is no opportunity to use the toolbox as the form is generic and is designed programatically?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As I told you in my previous comment you should try:

```
private Form1_FormClosing(...)
{
    timer.Stop();
    timer.Tick -= new EventHandler(OnTimer);
}
private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e) 
{
    timer.Dispose();
    timer = null;   
}
```

This is good because you prevent timer to cycle again (in FormClosing) and you can check in other parts (non in this example because you're closing the form, but as example) if that object (timer) has been *deleted* before using it.
So in other parts you can do

```
if (timer != null) // Note: this is false if you just use timer.Dispose()
{
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The only proper way to dispose disposable members of an `IDisposable` class is to do it inside its `Dispose(bool disposing)` method (check the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) article). In other words, you can open the autogenerated `Form.Designer.cs` file and put it inside the proper method.

On the other hand, if you add the `Timer` through VS Designer (instead of instantiating it yourself), it will get added to the `components` container:

```
// autogenerated inside Form.Designer.cs, InitializeComponent() method
this.timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer(this.components);
```

and then properly disposed when `components` member is disposed:

```
// autogenerated inside Form.Designer.cs, Dispose(bool disposing) method
if (disposing && (components != null))
{
    components.Dispose();
}
```

If you want to do this yourself, keep in mind that designer does not instantiate `components` if it doesn't think it's needed. So, `components` might be `null` in your case.

The simplest way to solve this: add the timer by dragging it from the toolbox, then start it inside the `Form_Load` handler.

Answer (score 1):

```
 private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e) 
 {        timer.Stop();    }
```

I shouldn't put the this.Dispose(); in form closing event just stop timer.

Answer (score 1):

The EventHandler is the persisting reference, remove the reference and Stop the timer on the [Closing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.closing%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) Event or as soon as its not required. If you want to check the Timer is disposed check it in the Closed Event

Answer (score 1):

The simple [`Timer.Dispose()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zb0225y6.aspx) deletes timer resources, including stoping the timer from firing in the future.

However, it is possible that after `Dispose()` returns, there are callbacks that are either actively executing or sitting in the thread pool's work queue waiting to execute.

The second overload,  [`Timer.Dispose(WaitHandle)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b97tkt95.aspx) will signal the passed in object once all callbacks for the timer have completed. This can be any `WaitHandle`, for instance a `ManualResetEvent`.

To simplify things, you can pass in `WaitHandle.InvalidHandle` and `Timer.Dispose()` will return only when all callbacks have completed. This avoids having to allocate a true event object and is usually what you want to do.

Since `WaitHandle` is abstract, you need to use a little hack, which is to create your own subclass.

```
class InvalidWaitHandle : WaitHandle {}
Timer tmr = new Timer(...);
tmr.Dispose(new InvalidWaitHandle);
```