# C# winform,what‘s “Form1.Close()" mean?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm a high school student and still a newbie to C# winform. I know if i use `Form1.Close()`, `Form1` will be closed!
At first I thought, if the code running to `Form1.Close()`, all the code related  `Form1` will stop running. But I found that's not true.

If I put a timer control on `Form1` and have a `timer1_Tick` event, if I use `Form1.Close()` to close `Form1`, is the `timer1` still running?

So, what's the `Form1.Close()` function mean, it's just mean the `Form` is not shown, and the coding related to `Form1` is still running?
I am not sure if I explained this well enough.

Comment: Look at the remarks section [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.close(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: please tag there correctly

Comment: @HenkHolterman . Yes,and i add a "return" after this.Close().

Comment: @JeroenHeier,Thanks,i'm not fully understand for my bad english.

Comment: @utility is it right now?

Comment: please post your coding efforts

Answer (score 1):

Though the form will be closed and its components disposed, you will still be subscribed to the events. Hence, you will have to unsubscribe from the events first.
[Here is the solution to your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7951821/timer-not-disposed-when-form-is) .  :)

Comment: Not when it's a WinForms.Timer. So it's the wrong timer or he uses DoEvents or ...

Answer (score 1):

The `Timer` will run until it is stopped or the application has been shutdown.

With your case the form will close, which will cause the application to shutdown as well. So the timer stops.