# how the label be updated time to time

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, label, timespan

I trap the time of the launch and the current time, but my problem is that the label does not change if the launch time is already past. I need to reopen my windows form (c#) so that the label will change.

Code:

```
_hh = DateTime.Now.Hour;
_min = DateTime.Now.Minute;
_yy = DateTime.Now.Year;
_mm = DateTime.Now.Month;            
_dd = DateTime.Now.Day;

DateTime _original_launch_time = new DateTime(_yy, _mm, _dd, 13, 0, 0);//this is the default time for launch
DateTime time = new DateTime(_yy, _mm, _dd, _hh, _min, 0); //this gets the current time

if (_original_launch_time > time)
{
    label1.Text = "your not late";
}
else
{
    label1.Text = "your late";
}
```

Comment: Did you take the label in Update Panel?

Comment: As you currently have it, your code will set `label1.Text` to "your not late" if the current time is before 1300 when the code is executed... can you clarify what exactly you want it to do differently? If you need it to automatically update after 1300, you need to put this code in a timer tick event, for example.

Comment: where can i find the update panel?

Answer (score 0):

Create a timer to execute your code for some time interval, and Invoke your code to be executed at the main thread to update the form properly, as the timer runs on a background thread.

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

Timer t = new Timer();
t.Interval = 1000;
t.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
t.Start();

void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => {

          // your code here

      }));
}
```

Don't forget to call `t.Stop();` when closing the form, as if you didn't do so, it will keep running until you close the whole app.

Comment: Timer t = new Timer();
t.Interval = 1000;
t.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
t.Start();

Comment: Note with a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`, it's not necessary to invoke back onto the GUI thread in the `Tick` event, it handles that already. Explicitly stopping the timer on form close isn't necessary either, if not referenced elsewhere it will get disposed and that'll happen anyway.

Comment: so you mean that i will use the invoker method?

Comment: @mat you may put the code at the form load event. @steve16351 I think you have a good point about not invoking the method with forms timer as the timer events is being raised on the UI thread, but he still should stop the timer and unsubscribe from `Tick` event when closing the form https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7951821/timer-not-disposed-when-form-is .